# Indian Income Tax - EVC done before payment was reflected

Tags: income-tax, india

I filled in the ITR-1 form and paid the income tax amount. However, I went ahead and filed the ITR and also immediately did the e-verification before the income tax paid amount was reflected in the Form26 AS or in my ITR - Acknowledgement.

My questions are

1. What should I now do given that I have an ITR-Acknowledgement which says Total Taxes Paid as 0 (when I have in fact paid it)?
2. How long should I wait for the Total Taxes Paid column to be filled in the ITR-Acknowledgement form?
3. Can I manually update the payment details?
4. Is it possible to refile my tax return and generate a new ITR-Acknowledgement where it mentions that Total Taxes Paid and Tax Payable as Nil

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to refile my tax return and generate a new ITR-Acknowledgement where it mentions that Total Taxes Paid and Tax Payable as Nil

Yes. You need to resubmit the ITR. You need to select "Original" or "Revised" question as "Revised". select the appropriate code. Enter the details of tax paid [along with BSR and other details] so that tax payable is NIL. Once you file this, you will get a revised acknowledgment.

Comment: Thanks! Where will the Original or Revised question be? Sorry to bother you, but can you please point me to the relevant section?

Comment: @Kanini First section after you enter your name and address.