# Income Tax India - Respond to Notice U/S 139(9) of Income Tax

Tags: income-tax, india

We did a mistake when we filed the ITR and the e-Verification before the payment was reflected. We then resubmitted the ITR as described [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/91872/1497). So, if I now login to Income Tax website and navigate to Income Tax returns, I see the following

[image]

The one with a status of **In Processing** with a Filing Date of 10/03/2018 is what has resulted in the notice. We have, however, as described above, waited for a couple of days for the payment to reflect and refiled the ITR (see the one dated 14/03/2018).

The notice has the following text in page 1.

[image]

In page 2, we have the following

[image]

It also says that we have to do the following

> To provide details or to submit the correcteded XML, kindly log on to www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in with your "username and password" and choose "e-File in response to notice u/s 139(9)" under the e-File section.

However, if I go into the e-File section there is nothing titled "e-File in response to notice u/s 139(9)". If I select Response to Notice u/s 139(9), I receive the following message.

No Responses found.

Where can I respond to this notice? I am worried.

To reiterate, we have paid the income tax and filed a revision when the Tax Payable (Item D18 of of ITR-1) was 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I respond to this notice?

Looks like they have sent you the notice based on the Original Return and it was automatically rectified by the Revised Return that you filed.

If there is any action due, it will be visible in the  "Response to Notice u/s 139(9)". If it is not them I assume it got auto rectified.